# How to create tests for functions in my case

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing

I am trying to test a timeout function in my app.

In my controller

```
$scope.$watch('toy',function(toyVar){
       if(toyVar == 1) {
        //do stuff       
        } else {
           $timeout(function() {
              $window.alert('toy is old');
           }, 3000);
        }
});
```

Test file.

```
describe('test', function () {
    var ctrl, scope;    
    beforeEach(module('testApp'));
    beforeEach(inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_) {
        scope = _$rootScope_.$new();

        ctrl = _$controller_('toyCtrl', {
            $scope: scope
        });
    }));

    describe('test here', function() {
        it('should check if timeout function works', function() {
            //not sure how to write test here.
        })
    })
});
```

I am not sure how to write test for `$timeout` portion of the codes. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do several things and the only way to be sure it got executed in this case, is seeing if the `alert` fired or not. Let's see those things:

- Spy on `$window.alert` to see whether it got called or not.
- Set something for `toy` different than 1
- Execute a `$digest` so the `$watch` runs.
- Call `flush` onto `$timeout` to simulate that the time passed and the function runs.
- Check that the `$window.alert` did run, meaning that everything worked.

Something like:

```
it('should check if timeout function works', function() {
  spyOn($window, 'alert');
  $scope.toy = 2;
  $scope.$digest();
  $timeout.flush();
  expect($window.alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith('toy is old');
});
```

And please, don't use the *underscore* syntax if you don't really need it.

See it working [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/JzZBue8A3QG0Bi69IiSa?p=preview)